# Search on array of multiple type objects

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I've following scenario in which I have main class abc having object array or another objects/classes.
my question is how can I can I search by name on class ABC using items property.

Items may have any object either OR or DT.

```
class abc
{

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OR", typeof(OR))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DT", typeof(DT))]
        public object[] Items {
            get {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
}

public class OR 
{

    public string name;

}

public class DT 
{

    public string name;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solutions

```
var data = from s in abc
                          from i in s.Items
                          select
                              new
                                  {
                                      objType = i.GetType() == typeof(OR)                                             
                                            ? ((OR)i).name : i.GetType() == typeof(DT)                                            
                                            ? ((DT)i).name : string.Empty,
                                      objAbc = s
                                  };

IEnumerable<abc> data = journey.Where(x => x.objType.Contains("myname")).Select(y => y.objAbc).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Derive your classes from an interface/abstract base class that has a Name property and make the Items property of abc class an array of that type...Your code will break if you add another class in future (checking for types in if else breaks Open Close principle in SOLID)